# How can I implement locking a range of values in a sorted sequence?

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, locking, sequence, systems-programming

I am trying to write a general purpose locking algorithm which allows me to lock a range of contiguous values in a sorted array. To start with, these could be exclusive locks - so two concurrent locks must be non-overlapping. What could be a good, scalable algorithm to do this? (Scalable ~ concurrent)

A specific example could be locking a range of contiguous bytes in a file for writing.

Concretely:
Let's say `{a_i}` is a valid sequence, for `i` = 0 through `N-1`, such that:

1. `a_j < a_k` for all j, k such that `0 <= j < k < N`.
2. `lock(a_j, a_k)` locks all elements from `a_j` through `a_k`.
3. While the above lock is held, another request `lock(a_x, a_y)` will succeed *only if* either `a_x > a_k`, or else `a_y < a_j`.

Comment: What would happen to a request if `a_x > a_j` and `a_y < a_k`?

Comment: It should block, or it should fail. It will not go through.

Comment: A locking mechanism [fcntl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) is available in Linux which does something very similar to your requirement. See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fcntl.html) too.

Comment: I am aware of fcntl's byte range locking. But this is asking about how such a system or an equivalent system for any other resource can be implemented.

Comment: Can you give an example of any other resource for which this can be applied?

Comment: Yes. I want to lock a range of contiguous ports, use them for communication and then release them.

Comment: @kiner_shah fcntl's byte-range locking is implemented using some algorithm, right? How is it done? I hope that's a valid a question. Moreover, this is not a POSIX compliant behavior but an extension. If I want common behavior across different Unix platforms, I will still need to code it.